# Is there a standard cordless home phone system that is also network connected for management?

Tags: telephony

My existing home phone is kind of useless and no one ever answers it because of that. It doesn't have any form of Caller ID and has very few settings, which means it's impossible to screen spam callers. Our phone line mainly exists for FAX purposes, but if I can find the right phone system, it'd be nice to be able to use the actual phone capabilities of it too.

So I'm wondering if anyone knows of a cordless phone system for homes that still uses the RJ-11 cable for connecting to the phone line (I don't have a choice in how the phone gets connected to the phone line, it has to use that cable), but can also either:

- Connect to a local network over Wi-Fi;
- *or* Connect to a local network via an Ethernet CAT-6 cable (essentially having two cables connected to the device simultaneously - one to the phone line, one to the network).

Having its own web interface for managing the phone system's setting is not necessary, but it should definitely have some sort of API so that requests can be made to the phone system in order to update various settings (like ring volume or blocked callers) as well as accessing data (like call history and voicemails) without having to use the phone itself.

It'd be really great if the phone system also allowed setting more fine-grained preferences on a per-number basis, having a default that applies to everything and can be overridden by the number's specific preferences similar to how most mobile phones operate.

Is anyone aware of such a home phone system or am I stuck trying to find alternate solutions (but let's be honest, I'd probably just give up)?

Comment: Why not just move it to VoIP? You can still run a separate fax service.